# Show that there exists the smallest algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ and $(A_i)$ a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{A}$. Show that there exists a sequence disjoint sets $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{A}$  such that 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$$

I manage to show the existence part, i.e. for all $n \geq 2$, $B_n=A_n\setminus \bigcup_{1=i}^{n-1}{A_n}$. I don't know how to show the equality $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}.$$

By using the definition of $B_n$, I can show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$, as for each $n$, $B_n \subset A_n$. But I have no avail on the other inclusion.

Comment: yeah, you were doing great, I hadn't realized you where doing good before I added my solution. But it includes the other inclusion you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is define $B_n$ as $A_n\setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$.

If $x$ appears in at least one $A_n$ you can let $A_k$ be the first one, and you have $x\in B_k$. On the other hand it is clear that $B_k\subseteq A_k$, so $\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

To prove that $B_k$ and $B_j$ with $k<j$ don't share elements notice that if $x\in B_k$ then $x\in A_k$ and so $x\in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}A_i$. So $x$ is not in $B_j$.

Comment: What do you meant by 'let $A_k$ be the first one'? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: yeah,  the smallest value $k$ such that $x\in A_k$